# Devise routing error while using multiple models - RAILS 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Actually I am using two models for my app that is User and Admin and I followed every steps to be dealt while using devise gem.

And I would like to have multiple login. When User logged in, must be redirected to respective profile and when Admin logged in, must be redirected to his respective profile.

I don't know where I am making mistake.

home/index.html.erb

```
<ul>
    <li>User:<%= link_to 'User', new_user_session_path, target: "_blank" %></li>
    <li>Admin:<%= link_to 'Admin', new_admin_session_path, target: "_blank" %></li>
</ul>
```

When I go to **User** link it gives me routing error which is as below;

[image: image1.png]

And When I go to **Admin** link it gives me routing error which is as below;

[image: image2.png]

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root "home#index"

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
        sessions: 'users/sessions',
        registrations: 'users/registrations'
      }   

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'aslani#index', as: 'authenticated_user_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'aslani#index', as: 'unauthenticated_user_root'
    end
  end

  devise_for :admins, controllers: {
        sessions: 'admins/sessions',
        registrations: 'admins/registrations'
      }

  devise_scope :admin do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'yaseen#index', as: 'authenticated_admin_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'yaseen#index', as: 'unauthenticated_admin_root'
    end
  end

end
```

aslani/index.html.erb

```
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          I am Aslani.
           <%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to 'Log In', new_user_session_path %>
          <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path %>
        <% end %>
```

kola/index.html.erb

```
    <% if admin_signed_in? %>
       I am Kola.
      <%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to 'Log In', new_admin_session_path %></li>
      <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_admin_registration_path %>
    <% end %>
```

app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

```
 class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
       def new
        super
       end

       def create
          self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
          set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if  is_navigational_format?
          sign_in(resource_name, resource)
          if !session[:return_to].blank?
            redirect_to session[:return_to]
            session[:return_to] = nil
          else
             respond_with resource, :location =>      after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
          end
     end
   end
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are taking the sessions contoller under the users name space,

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
        sessions: 'users/sessions',
        registrations: 'users/registrations'
}
```

Your sessions_controller path should be,

```
app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

    class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
       def new
        super
       end

       def create
          self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
          set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if  is_navigational_format?
          sign_in(resource_name, resource)
          if !session[:return_to].blank?
            redirect_to session[:return_to]
            session[:return_to] = nil
          else
             respond_with resource, :location =>      after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
          end
     end
   end
```

The form you have taken in the que should be in `app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb`

```
  <h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What data will I put in the new file users/session_controller.rb

Comment: It shoud contain the action which creates the user session, I updated the ans please check

Comment: You should not have a form or html in the controller

Comment: Thanks. but 
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Users::SessionsController

Comment: changed the answer please check, if you want users name space,
 `class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`

Comment: Thanks. but
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Users::SessionsController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117876/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-sravan).

Comment: Hope you are doing great. How about Registrations controller? Same as sessions controller logic?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your controller in routes as

`devise_for :users, controllers: {
      registrations: 'registrations',
      sessions: 'sessions',
      passwords: 'passwords',
      confirmations: 'confirmations',
    }`

and keep your controller as app/controllers/session_controller.rb will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What will I put in the new file /session_controller.rb

Comment: Again it gives me 
Routing Error
uninitialized constant SessionsController

Comment: Thanks, Please have a look at my session_controller.rb.

Comment: You should never create form in controller. Controller should always contain an action, and redirection logic.